# How do you debug in codeworld?

Tags: haskell, codeworld

In http://codeworld.info/, you can only draw/print/display data in types of Text and Number (and you need Show to convert Number to Text). So what can I do to let codeworld draw something that is neither a Text or Number?

Comment: What types of things are you trying to draw?

Comment: It's possible to override the `Prelude.show` although it's fairly ugly https://gist.github.com/nisstyre56/12b69ef9b6fe2aa87b6e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chris recently added the ability to import the Haskell base library into CodeWorld, so you can do [this](http://www.codeworld.info/run.html?hash=PbUhVFD3gzdSiGVQiShqMdQ==):

```
import Prelude hiding (show)
import HaskellPrelude (show)

showT(x) = fromString(show(x))

main = pictureOf(text(showT([1,2,3,4,5])))
```